# How to play mp4 in iOS Flex application

Tags: ios, apache-flex, video, mobile, flex4.5

I'm developing a Flex application to iOS devices and I can't find a way to play mp4 video inside it...

I know it works with navigate to URL command but it's open browser and then the vieo player, which is not what I'm intending...

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm trying to do the same thing now, but i'd be okay with the app calling the native video player. how did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with audio and video streaming, one of the worst limitation of AIR 2.6 for iOS is that it is not possible to stream video encoded in H.264 (and audio in AAC) inside your AIR application. AIR 2.6 for iOS supports NetConnection and NetStream but can decode only Spark, VP6, MP3, NellyMoser and Speex formats. So no H.264 and no AAC.

I've tried play .flv video fine in flex app on iOS.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for the AAC so far? I have to make an APP and it has to play AAC. So far I have gotten it to work in Android, but not iOS yet